# CloudFront - Creating a signed URL using a custom policy and custom condition

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, access-token, policy

I want to create a sign url to s3 files and I want to let access only to requests that contain an Authorization token, according to the AWS developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html there is only three Conditions that I can set: DateLessThan, DateGreaterThan, IpAddress. There is an option to add a custom condition that checks my token?